# How to remove E from float big number?

Tags: java, android, floating-point

I've a float data in my code, i need to get the string out of it . 
the problem is , when I have big number like  10000000 ,It converts the number to something like this : 
1.0E7

How can I convert it to the actual number ?

Comment: check the answer  I had tested and working proper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

follow this way to get the actual number

```
   float firstNumber = (float) 1.0E7;
    String firstNumberAsString = String.format("%.0f", firstNumber);
    Log.v(" OUt-Put", firstNumberAsString);
```

It will Give you:

```
android V/  OUt-Put: 10000000
```